# How to let PHP run some script after the connection end

Tags: php, ajax, connection

This is my system's flow:

```
                Form
User Input  ───────────►    Encrypt Library Scripts
                                           │
                                           │
Result     ◄─────────   Add DB    ◄────────┤
```

However, The script file is encrypted and something is missing.
Also I want to add the log about this function.

So I am writing some code like this:

Frontend

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     
     // Call API Here

     this.submit();
});
```

```
// Step 1: API to Save the User Input and timestamp to the log table

// Step 2: Cron job to Query the latest result of that user, and update the table id to the Step 1 log
```

But it seems too complicated and need to manage the cron job.

So I want to write something like this

API

```
$data = $_POST['inputA']; 
...
..

// Step 1: Return the response to frontend first (Finish AJAX)
// Step 2: Wait 10s for the library adding result
// Step 3: Query the latest id, and add with the $_POST data from frontend

// Will Handle if the latest result not in 10s, assume add data failed , no need to retry
```

Is it possible in php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flushe all response data to the client

```
fastcgi_finish_request();
sleep(10);
// do your task
```

Or better way is to use queques
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues